# how do I join multiple tables if one table doesn't have the reference?

Tags: mysql, database, join

There are several tables that need to be joined.

Here's one thing I don't get it to work. Let's start with a table named systems. I want to join with two more tables, say, a harddrives table and a opticaldrive table. Not all systems have an optical drive.

How do I execute if no optical drive exists?

```
SELECT *
FROM systems sys, 
diskdrives dd,
opticaldrives od 
WHERE
sys.id = dd.system_id
AND
sys.id = od.system_id
```

It doesn't seem to work, it keeps returning zero result - I suspect it doesn't find the reference in opticaldrive table to match the id of system so it just won't return results. How do I make them join and display the results even if optical drive does not exist? The results can display NULL if optical drive data is not available for that system id.

Comment: Review this Visual aid for working with SQL and sets. http://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

Comment: whats the difference between left join and left outer join?

Comment: LEFT and left outer are the same function using different syntax.  They resolve to the same database operations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a true `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM systems sys
    LEFT JOIN diskdrives dd ON sys.id = dd.system_id
    LEFT JOIN opticaldrives od ON sys.id = od_system_id
```

Using `LEFT JOIN` will tell the server to match with null values in place of the opticaldrives table values if there is no match on `sys.id = od_system_id`.

Comment: +1 for explaining how the LEFT JOIN helps to return records in the event of a null in a joining table.